# Does delegatecall() use only the calling function?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, storage, delegatecall, state-variable

Let me explain with the code:

```
contract A {
 function f() public {
  [...]
  g();
}

 function g() private {
  [...]
 }
}

contract B {
 A a;
 function delegateA() public {
  (bool success, ) = address(a).delegatecall(abi.encodeWithSignature("f()"));
 }
}
```

If B uses delegatecall() to call f() with its own storage, is a problem avoiding to write even the g() function on the B contract? I mean, I know that the structure of the storage of A must be the same as B, and the functions don't partecipate to it, so what about directly not writing the private functions which are used by A?

Comment: If you don't define the `g` function, which is called by `f`, your code won't compile at all.

Comment: No I meant the avoidance of writing the g function in the B contract. I've already tested it and it compiles, because delegateA function cannot know what kind of function it's gonna call in the A contract. My question is about the storage, I mean, if I don't write g in B, will the storage be different between the two contracts?

Comment: @PaulRazvanBerg You were right, I've set up correctly everything now. What do you think?